# Download pdf in Webview didnt work ( Error Can only download HTTP/HTTPS Uri: Blob )

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-webview, android-download-manager

i make android app with webview for my website, but when i try to download pdf file i always get error  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:http://lapor.infokanimsambas.com/a0d3f9a5-81ce-434d-99a3-52ae66348ea2
im using downloadlistener, this is my code :

```
@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.os_view);
    assert webView != null;
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    webView.loadUrl(webview_url);
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                    url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading FIle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and this is the error log :

```
2021-04-15 09:13:16.790 6870-6870/mgks.os.fileup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mgks.os.fileup, PID: 6870
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:http://lapor.infokanimsambas.com/a0d3f9a5-81ce-434d-99a3-52ae66348ea2
    at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.<init>(DownloadManager.java:468)
    at mgks.os.fileup.MainActivity$1.onDownloadStart(MainActivity.java:149)
    at Cs.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.apk-stable-410410681:156)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

can anybody help me???

Comment: Does `String url` have `blob:` at the beginning? If so get rid of it?

Comment: No, when i use browser the url doesnt containt blob and when i click download button it is automatically download file, but why in my android app ( webview ) these error said "Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:http://lapor.infokanimsambas.com/a0d3f9a5-81ce-434d-99a3-52ae66348ea2" i got confuse??

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue the onDownloadStart param url was appended with `blob:`. I Just removed it from the url and it worked like a charm.

url that was coming from method -> blob:http://lapor.infokanimsambas.com/a0d3f9a5-81ce-434d-99a3-52ae66348ea2

url that I had to use -> http://lapor.infokanimsambas.com/a0d3f9a5-81ce-434d-99a3-52ae66348ea2

Answer (score 0):

apart from using the webview   you can use the action view intent to directly jump on to the browser and just pass the url inside it or else you can try the volley library

Comment: But my project is to convert website to android app, like facebook app, so it's useless if my app redirect to browser, and i stuck in this download function.